# How to draw a semi circle in Adobe Photoshop CS3?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, cs3

How can we draw a semi circle or half a circle in Photoshop CS3? WE can draw a complete circle by using the shape method or tool. If we want to crop the image to get a semi circle or half a circle, When we crop an image usually the image is cropped and resized in the background of the layer to form the whole layer. If we want to create a half circle, what will be the procedure. I am using Adobe Photoshop CS3.

Comment: You can use the direct selection tool to mark an anchor point on a circle shape and then delete it thus making a half circle.

Answer (score 3):

- Draw a circle using the Ellipse Tool + <kbd>Shift</kbd>
- Press <kbd>Alt</kbd> and use the Rectangle Tool to start drawing a rectangle
  shape from outside the circle until the center. Release <kbd>Alt</kbd> to make the rectangle from one corner to the next.

When drawing a shape on top of another, the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key subtract

[image]

Comment: You don't need to hold the Alt key beyond pressing it and the mouse button at the same time.

Comment: Using the same method with the marquee tools will produce a semicircle selection

Answer (score 3):

Lazy method:

- Draw the circle with the Ellipse tool
- With the Direct Selection tool (<kbd>A</kbd>, the white arrow) select one of the anchors and delete.

Works great if all you want is a simple quick semicircle filled with color.

**Drawback:** it might cause trouble if you try to use stroke or other path operations (because it's an open shape). In which case I'd do it as Danielillo's answer.

Comment: Or you could close the shape after, or make it a Custom Shape for that matter.

Comment: I tried but when I deleted one of the anchor points, the shape changed but not semi circle. I was not able to get the semi - circle by deleting anchor points.

Comment: @PushkalSingh the shape changed to what? You have to use the Direct Selection tool, not the Path tool (shortcut P) otherwise you don't get the correct result.

Comment: Thanks. I was able to change the shape to semi-circle using the shortcut P. It worked to create the semi-circle.